# How to Increment a Variable in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

When trying to use the supervisor in Tensorflow I was made aware that :

> your training op is responsible for incrementing the global step value.

([Reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/supervisor/index.md))

So how do you increment a variable in a graph in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pretty simple solution:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(1, name='global_step', trainable=False, dtype=tf.int32)
increment_global_step_op = tf.assign(global_step, global_step+1)
```

Then when you want to increment it, just run that op under the current `tf.Session` `sess`.

```
step = sess.run(increment_global_step_op)
```

The result placed in `step` is the value of the incremented variable after the increment.  In this case, the value of global_step after being incremented.  So `2`.

If you're using this for global_step like me, run it along with your `training_op`.

```
result = sess.run([out, increment_global_step_op], {x: [i]})
```

Comment: +1 for putting trainable=False. Note that the assign method can be substituted by tf.assign_add(global_step, 1)

Comment: What I do not understand is how the global_step correlates with my optimizer? Do I have to explicitly tell the optimizer that the `global_step` variable is my global step or how does this work?

Comment: If we are going to divide some number with the variable `global_step` later on, would it be better if we declare it with `dtype=tf.float32` or `tf.float64` instead of `tf.int32`?

Answer (score 12):

Incrementing/decrementing the value is a common operation, so TF has operations to simplify the graph creation: [`tf.assign_add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) and [`tf.assign_sub()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_sub). They combine two operations (`tf.assign()` and `tf.add`/`tf.sub`).

Here is the example of use:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0, name='counter')
inc = tf.assign_add(x, 1, name='increment')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for _ in xrange(5):
        print sess.run(inc)
```

if you will compare the tensorboard graph in this example and in your own example, you will see that the graph has less amount of nodes.

Comment: What needs to be done if the variable was not part of original graph? When using `retrain.py` from Tensorflow website for transfer learning, i am trying to save images from open cv frames with unique names.. in that case the increment op gives me error `ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'increment:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("increment:0", shape=(), dtype=int32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)`