# Tensorflow equivalent of x = x + 1

Tags: tensorflow

So I tried the following

```
x = tf.Variable(0.10, tf.float32)
tf.assign(x, tf.add(x,1))
```

and

```
x = tf.Variable(0.10, tf.float32)
x = x + 1
```

But they don't work. Any idea how do we do such a function in TensorFlow?

Whole code for completeness

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.Variable(0.10, tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(1.00, tf.float32)
x.assign(1.0)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
x = sess.run(x)
print(x)
```

**Update: Solution**
Whole code for completeness. It's simply just ensuring you have `x = x.assign(1.0)` instead of simply `x.assign(1.0)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.Variable(0.10, tf.float32)
y = tf.constant(1.00, tf.float32)
x = x.assign(1.0)
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
x = sess.run(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable.

```
w = tf.Variable(<initial-value>, name=<optional-name>)
```

Assign a new value to the variable with `assign()` or a related method.

```
w.assign(w + 1.0)
w.assign_add(1.0)
```

*Updated for completeness:*

In you case it should would be:

```
x = tf.Variable(0.10, tf.float32)
op = x.assign_add(1.0)
x = sess.run(op)
```

Taken from the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variables)

Comment: I tried that, it returns 0.1 still (the original value). Any idea? I edited my post for the whole code (simple) to show you how it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like the assign op needs to be run. Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671956/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-tensorflow) one out.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I played with the idea and we have to use the same `var` name instead of a new one in that link. Updated the code with the changes.